# MVC - Retain model result for use in ajax method without passing in via JSON?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Long time lurker first time posting, so hey!

TL:DR - how would I keep a value from the original page-loading-controller to the ajax method without passing it in as a json object as part of the ajax request? And I can't use Session[]!

Backstory - I'm working on a filter-search functionality which brings back a big list of objects on the initial page load, generated from a database call and populates `Model.FullResults`.

In order to filter the results, rather than keep doing more database calls each time a filter is clicked, I'm simply filtering the results via linq in an AJAX method, like so:

```
var fullResults = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FullResults));
var obj = {
            //filter tickboxes statuses etc are here
            fullResults: fullResults
        }
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            //urls etc removed for clarity 
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            success: function (response) {
                //stuff
                }
            }

        });
```

Which is all working perfectly fine for small values of Model.FullResults. However, if `Model.FullResults` is pretty large (i.e. on my main search page), this is a large amount of data to pass across via ajax each time, and the only reason I'm even passing it across this way is just for the plain and simple fact of I don't know how else I can "keep" this data from the original controller action and still have it for use the ajax method.

Storing `Model.FullResults` in Session was a brief thought, but there's a high probability people will open multiple tabs that hit the same controller, thus making session outdated. Something like Viewdata would be ideal but I can't access that in the ajax method of course.

So how would I keep this value for use in the ajax method? Do I have to resort to doing another database call OR passing it into the ajax method? There must be a way of retaining it somehow?

Thanks in advance you helpful bunch! :)

Comment: That is simply crazy, and is degrading performance (passing all that data across the wire instead of making an database call which will be faster). And you can always cache the collection in `MemoryCache` to avoid database calls.

Comment: And if you are initially displaying all records, then you can just use javascript to filter the result on the client.

Comment: There's more reasons to why I've used Ajax rather than simple javascript to hide the non-matching results. But yes, "That is simply crazy" is the exact reason I made an account to post this question lol. I have indeed used caching but just `HttpContext.Cache` rather than `MemoryCache` but yes, caching was indeed the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for memoryCache to save large amount of data. Similer problem was with me where I have to read data from csv file and pass through Web API. Every-time, reading data from text was not a good idea, So I saved data in memory cache and fetching the records from memoryCache to avoid reading from stream. A simple demo is shown on my github account.you can co relate it.
https://github.com/abhee235/SimpleRestfulAPI/tree/master/DataProvider

Note : The project is not optimized for performance point of view. It is just a demo.

Comment: Fab! :) I haven't really needed to use caching so far in my web dev career, but now that I think about it this is the perfect time to use it. I had a brief look at your example but it used `using System.Runtime.Caching` and looked like a more complex implementation than I needed, in the end I've used a very basic HttpContext.Cache[id] to store and fetch what I needed, but your reply definitely pushed me in that direction. Thank you :)

Comment: It is using System.Runtime.Caching because caching of data is done in different layer and not in asp.net web application layer. Anyway i am happy that  worked you can upvote it too. :) @ChrisPollock